# np.around() is displaying rounded digits

Tags: python, numpy, printing, rounding

I am currently writing code to perform a torsional vibration modal analysis.  I already have a time-domain version of this software for comparison for results.  I know this is going to be asked so, time-domain analysis isn't easy to incorporate complex-valued structural damping.  It is very easy to do so in modal analysis thought.  My code is working and produces output that is the right shape, that is it oscillates the same number of times per cycle as the dominant frequencies being analyzed, but it does not produce output with the correct scale.  I'm assuming that I made a unit conversion error somewhere along the line.  What I'm doing right now is verifying that different ways to calculate the same quantities produce the same results.  Fairly easy to do by visual inspection.

For some reason, np.around() will work as it should some of the time but not all the time.  Below you can see that both print statements use almost identical formatting but they produce completely different results.  "Developing model" prints out rounded numbers w/o trailing zeroes.  On the other hand, "Natural frequencies" prints trailing zeroes out to 5 decimal places.

I thought that maybe np.sqrt() was causing the problem but you can also see below that a similar output is not providing the trailing zeroes after rounding.  I've also tried using np.asarray() and np.asmatrix() just to check them off the list of possible culprits.  I'm assuming that there is some sort of data transformation going on in the background that I can't see and don't know about that is causing np.around() to do this.

Next, I tried suppressing the numpy use of scientific notation.  This corrected some of the print statements outputs, but not all of them.

Any help would be helpful...

[Developing model code snip-it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHM2h.png)

[Developing model output snip-it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSrRj.png)

[Natural Frequencies code snip-it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM1xo.png)

[Natural frequencies output snip-it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A21Vn.png)

[np.sqrt() consideration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjehj.png)

Comment: It seems that `np.around` is working as intended; it *is* rounding the values to the specified number of decimal places in both cases. Your values are correct.

You are seeing differences because of the formatting of the output of `print`. I suggest taking a look at [np.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) if you would like to force consistency in the printed output.

Comment: (Having looked at it a bit further it seems np.set_printoptions does  not work for Numpy scalars (which are used here due to the imaginary component of the numbers), but as I said above the discrepancy you are seeing here is only in how the values are displayed by `print`.

Comment: FinleyGibson.  I agree with the first comment but have never looked into numpy scalars.  I will tell you that when I suppressed the scientific notation most of the printed values came out looking the way I need them to and was able to visually inspect the data.  Having done that I found that one way to calculate values had a small error of unknown significance.  Thank you.